# Requesting mp4 byte ranges based on time

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, quicktime, mp4parser

I have a partial mp4 file, containing the `fytp` and `moov` atoms and an incomplete `mdat` atom. Is it possible to use the information in the `stbl` atom to determine the byte offset of a frame calculated from an arbitrary time?

With this byte offset information, is it possible to request one frame of the complete mp4 and modify the `mdat` atom to include just that single frame?

Comment: The answer is Yes to both questions.